# How to get the twitter feeds of my app only?

Tags: objective-c, ios4, ios5, twitter, twitter-oauth

I want to fetch the feeds which are posted by my iPhone app's users on to **my twitter app**.

I found this URL - http://search.twitter.com/search.json?q=serachKeyword&result_type=recent

This will return to us a dictionary result which contains an array of tweets that matches with the **serachKeyword**.

But i want to fetch only the feeds which are posted via my **twitter app**.

Is there any way to fetch only my twitter application feeds not all?
Can i **filter** the search results or something like it?

Answer (score 0):

The [Twitter API](https://dev.twitter.com/docs/using-search) says yes, you can filter by source.

The Search Operators section says:

> news source:tweet_button | containing "news" and entered via the Tweet Button

The Source section says:

> • can only be combined with a keyword parameter. If you do not include a keyword you will receive an HTTP 403 error with the message: {"error":"You must enter a query."}.
>
> • supports multi-word sources by using _ instead of spaces. For example, the source "Tweet Button" should be entered as source: tweet_button

So you must have a keyword parameter and if your client name has spaces in it replace them with underscores.

Answer (score 0):

There is no complete method to do this. As @JoePasq answered you can search on source but you must include a keyword and Twitter search is filtered for quality and relevance.

> - Search is focused in relevance and not completeness. This means that some Tweets and users may be missing from search results.
> - The Search API is not complete index of all Tweets, but instead an index of recent Tweets.

What you should do is have your application post a request to a server you control every time a user posts a tweet with the `status_id`. This way you can store a complete database of all tweets posted from your app and query the data as needed.

Comment: I can do this by handle the post on my server, but i don't feel this is a better way to do so..And I really didn't get the search on source, Can you please help me with any such **URL** to filter tweet results.

Comment: This URL will search by your source but as you can see it doesn't show any results. https://twitter.com/#!/search/realtime/source%3AserachKeyword%20news

Comment: Thanks Abraham This URL working good...  I use My App name in the place of AsearchKeyword and it gives results of all those tweet which was posted via my app. Thanks again..But it gives the result on twitter page, i want results in the form of JSON or XML.

Comment: The issues in my answer still apply. That search will not return all results. You already know the API URL as you have it in your question. You just have to change the paramaters.